# バッチファイル読み込み時、出力ファイルが文字化けする

Tags: batch-file

SJISで書かれたものをxmlファイルへ書き出すというバッチファイルを作っています。

SJISに取り込みをしてXMLファイルで確認すると日本語表記が文字化けしたり、文字がないというエラーが発生します。

例
SJIS（例AAA.TXT）

```
1,パンダ
2,羊
・・・
```

XML（AAAXML）

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<Code Code="1"  content="
```

となります。

おそらくファイル中にutf-8が入っているのにもかかわらず
SJISを使っているのでIE等でみると文字がなくなってしまうのかと思われますが
SJISを取り込みはSJISでも保存するときに、UTF-8に変換して保存できないでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします。

簡単な取り込み文は
for /f %%a in (AAA.TXT) do ( ECHO %%a>>AAA.XML ) です。

Comment: ”for /f %%a in (AAA.TXT) do ( ECHO %%a>>AAA.XML ) ””が実行される前の、AAA.XMLファイルの内容はどうなっていたのですか？　単純にECHOでAAA.TXTから読みだした文字を書き込むだけだと、””<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>というような行は書き込まれないと思うのですが。

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>は自動的に差し込みました。ECHO文を使ってです。

Comment: 質問には可能な限り [”再現可能な" 実際のサンプルコード](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) を含めるようにしてください。 / パスワードの類はもちろん伏せて構いませんが、あまり省略された部分が多いようだと確認のやり取りが増えてしまうだけであまりいい結果になりません。

Answer (score 1):

バッチファイルの実行環境(CMD.EXEとその関連のWindows標準コマンド)では、1行のコマンド/スクリプトの中で入力ファイル文字コード、作業変数、出力ファイル文字コードを別々に指定して、しかもそれをUTF-8にすることはまず出来ないでしょう。

以下のいずれか、あるいはそのバリエーションで対処するのが良いと思われます。

- XMLファイルにするまでの処理は、いったんすべてシフトJISで行い、その後 nkf, iconv, その他何かのスクリプトやコマンドでUTF-8に変換する
- PowerShellやPython等の、入力文字コード/出力文字コードを別々に指定できるスクリプトツールやコマンドで処理を構築する